# How to use fetch and call rest api

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-hooks, fetch, flask-restful

How to add fetch in the above code
I was trying to call a rest API using fetch in setEffect but I am getting the error.

Goal: to call the rest API when I submit the form.
Till now I was able to generate URL dynamically from form and was unable to connect to fetch and call the rest API.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ form, setForm ] = useState({});

  function handleSubmit() {
    const uri = `http://example.com/?${form.one}&${form.two}`;
    console.log(`Current state: ${JSON.stringify(form)}`);
    console.log(`Fetch URI: ${uri}`);
    // fetch(uri)... etc
  }


  function handleChange(e) {
    const { nodeName, name, value } = e.target;
    if (nodeName === 'INPUT') {
      setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onChange={handleChange}>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Input one</legend>
        <input name="one" value={form.one} />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Input two</legend>
        <input name="two" value={form.two} />
      </fieldset>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

[image: 400 bad request error]
[image: output of the api]

Comment: To start, `onChange` should be on the input elements, not the form. you should make the button `type="submit"`. you should add `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` on the form. inside `handleSubmit` you should add the event and prevent the default behavior `handleSubmit(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }`. Now that that's out of the way, have you looked up how to do a fetch request? have you looked at how to set a state value from that fetch request?

Answer (score 1):

To start, onChange should be on the input elements, not the form. you should make the button type="submit". you should add onSubmit={handleSubmit} on the form. inside handleSubmit you should add the event and prevent the default behavior handleSubmit(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... }.

then you can call your fetch api in handleSubmit.

```
        const { useState } = React;
        
        function Example() {  
               const [ form, setForm ] = useState({one:'',two:''});
                function handleSubmit(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    const uri = `http://example.com/?$one=
{form.one}&tow=${form.two}`;
                    fetch(uri, {
                        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.)
                        body: JSON.stringify(form),
                    }).then(r=>{
                        console.log(r)
                    })
                    // console.log(`Current state: ${JSON.stringify(form)}`);
                    // console.log(`Fetch URI: ${uri}`);
                    // fetch(uri)... etc
                }
            
            
                function handleChange(e) {
                    const { nodeName, name, value } = e.target;
                    if (nodeName === 'INPUT') {
                        setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });
                    }
                }
              return (
                <div >
                    <form onChange={handleSubmit}>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Input one</legend>
                            <input name="one" value={form.one} onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Input two</legend>
                            <input name="two" value={form.two} onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </fieldset>
                        <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
              );
    };
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Example />,
      document.getElementById('react')
    );
```

that works for me very well.

Comment: getting 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Comment: When you make an uri like :http://example.com/?${form.one}&${form.two}   or you put http://example.com/?one=${form.one}&tow=${form.two}

Comment: Please check the query uri if the problem is not related to the payload

Comment: @harsh so there's a problem with your API, not with react.

Comment: @Samira `https://flask-api-test1.herokuapp.com/predict?solute=${form.one}&solvent=${form.two}` This is the api i was using

Comment: @Shahriar The API is working well i have posted the images above please take a look

Comment: Are you sure your api post is method?beacuse in second image you have called your api and it has worked !!!

Comment: Is that a CORS error?